# How to store int in Core Data with NSTableView binding NSArrayController?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I'm developing a core data a application and I have a attribute of an entity that have type "integer16" (int).
I would to set it through a `NSTableView`, that is bind to core data through a `NSArrayController`.

I put a `NSDateFormatter` in the `NSTableViewColumn` to format the date's column, and it works because `NSDateFormatter` returns a `NSDate`.
But with `NSNumberFormatter` doesn't work, because `NSNumberFormatter` returns a `NSNumber`, not int or `NSInteger` (the type set in core data).

Where can I call the method `[mynsnumber intValue]` to set the int value in my core data every time user changes the value?

Answer (score 1):

Because you haven't explained why you're trying to store a date as an integer, I'm going to go for the obvious answer: Use a date type to store a date in Core Data.

If it's not a date, then you really need to explain - in detail - exactly what you're trying to accomplish, rather than ask us how to force it to work the way you think it should.

Specific questions in my mind: What *exactly* does this attribute represent? How do you want to represent it to your user (how *should* it be formatted - note I'm not asking you what formatter you want to use; what is the *goal*, not the *means* you assumed would get you there)?

Comment: I would store a date AND a integer, in two different column.
For the date I have solved with a NSDateFormatter in the NSTableViewColumn. But for the int, I don't know how formatter can I use.

Comment: This doesn't clarify your goal at all. If it's separate from your date problem, why mention the date problem? Please clarify the specific questions I've asked.

Comment: I have no date problem! The date works perfectly with the NSDateFormatter. I mentioned "the date problem" because I wanted explain what I've done to store the date. Now I want to do the same thing, but with an int. I can't do it because the NSNumberFormatter transform the value in a NSNumber and core data instead store int (while NSDateFormatter return NSDate and core data store NSDate, so it's ok).

If I am not clear, I apologize, but I don't know how else to explain me.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: So to make sure I understand: You want to use an int with two systems (Bindings and Core Data) that require an int to be packaged in an NSNumber? Just use an NSNumber throughout (specifically, as your property) and you'll be fine. Convert any direct uses of this property in your code to ask the result of [[self myProperty]; intValue] or set with [self setMyProperty:[NSNumber numberWithInt:someNewInt]];.\